# How do I read functional composition in es6/javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, composition

**Background:**

> Composition is putting two functions together to form a third function where the output of one function is the input of the other.

No matter how much I look at this I struggle with how to read it.  In particular why the `compose()` return `=> (a) =>` captures the `121.2121212` in local scope. Also I struggle with how final fn `f(g(a))` would look with all the values/fn present w/o the use of variables.

**Question:** Does anyone have any techniques or diagrams for quickly reading examples like this; how can I mentally debug and follow the function flow?

[Reference:](https://github.com/hemanth/functional-programming-jargon#function-composition)

```
const compose = (f, g) => (a) => f(g(a)) // Definition
const floorAndToString = compose((val) => val.toString(), Math.floor) // Usage

floorAndToString(121.212121) // '121'
```

Comment: When I was first getting used to arrow functions, I found it useful to rewrite them as `function` functions (at least, the ones like the above that don't care about `this`) in order to understand them. The above is primarily tricky because `compose` is a function accepting functions that returns a new function, all using the concise arrow form. You do get used to it, but I for one found it challenging at first and found that strategy useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by T.J. Crowder, it often helps rewriting arrow functions as regular functions. So the function:

```
const compose = (f, g) => (a) => f(g(a))
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
function compose (f, g) {
    return function (a) {
        return f(g(a));
    }
}
```

Now it is perhaps more obvious what's going on. So now let's rewrite the other parts:

```
const floorAndToString = compose((val) => val.toString(), Math.floor)
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
function convertToString (val) { return val.toString() };

const floorAndToString = compose(convertToString, Math.floor);
```

Now it may be more obvious that the `compose` function will return the function:

```
// remember that we pass `convertToString` as `f`
// and `Math.floor` as `g`:

function (a) {
    return convertToString(Math.floor(a));
}
```

So it's obvious that the function `floorAndToString` simply returns the result of `convertToString(Math.floor(a))`. There is nothing special about `compose` that captures `121.2121212` because it doesn't. Instead it creates a function where `121.2121212` can be passed as an argument to `convertToString(Math.floor(a))`.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to look at the Wikipedia article for [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). But I think your problem is not really related to function composition but to the arrow notation in general.

Maybe it helps to look at a simpler example first:

```
const addOne = (x) => x + 1
const addN = (n) => (x) => x + n
const addSeven = addN(7)
```

The last line produces a new function that adds seven to the input `(x) => x + 7`. You can think of the parameter tuples between the arrows as being filled from left to right when values are provided (and the variables to the right are bound to these values). As long as you don't provide all parameters, you will obtain a new function.

You can also provide all parameters like this:

```
addN(5)(3) // yields 8
```

Note that addN can be seen as taking two parameters but in separate bracket pairs. The arrows between the brackets in the definition kind of allow you to omit parameters to the right and obtain a function with fewer parameters with the left ones being already fixed.

Let's look at an alternative definition of compose:

```
const weirdCompose = (f, g, a) => f(g(a))
```

It should be clear how it works, but the problem is that you cannot use this to compose two functions without evaluating the result of the composition with the value `a` right away. By separating the parameters into two groups you can [partially apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) the function and only provide `f` and `g` in a first step.

To understand this better, I suggest you also have a look at the concept of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)