# How to combine functions in another FP?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I am learning function programming in JavaScript, currently I have the following code.

I would like to combine this two functions in another function which alllow an user to pass a value in and having the result equal to the value passed plus 10 multiply 3 using the following functions.

Pseudo code example:

```
 const myFormulat= add(10).multiply(3);
```

How can I write this function using only vanilla JS ES6?

```
function add(x){
  return function(y){
    return y + x;
  };
}

function multiply(x){
  return function(y){
    return y * x;
  };
}

// my calculation
// get x add 10 and after multiply by 3
```

Comment: You would you use `myFormulat`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read functional composition in es6/javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823053/how-do-i-read-functional-composition-in-es6-javascript)

Comment: What You actually want to achieve? Because Your snippet is kind of confusing.
Your function compositors are returning functions, which is correct approach, but Your const declaration, calls function **add** and then tries to invoke **multiply** on returned value - which is not correct.

Comment: What is "*another FP*"? How would you do it in the standard FP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bear traps and landmines**

This answer exists solely to demonstrate why this is not such a great idea – complexity is *thru* the roof with basically no gain. Note we must tell our function when to end, so i've added a special function `call` so our expressions will look like this

```
.add(3).mult(4).call(x)
// where x is the input for the entire function chain
```

One last change is our library of functions `add`, `mult`, et al must be wrapped in some scope that limits the reach of our proxy. This scope tells us exactly where the functions we wish to chain exist.

Oh and if the title of this section wasn't a warning enough, we use a `Proxy` too.

```js
// helpers
const identity = x => x
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x))

// magic wand
const using = scope => {
  let acc = identity
  let p = new Proxy({
    call: x => acc(x),
  }, {
    get: (target, name) => {
      if (name in target)
        return target[name]
      else if (name in scope)
        return x => {
          acc = comp (scope[name](x)) (acc)
          return p
        }
      else
        throw Error(`${f} is not undefined in ${scope}`)
    }
  })
  return p
}

// your functions wrapped in a scope
const math = {
  add: x => y => x + y,
  mult: x => y => x * y
}

// chain it up
const main = using(math).add(3).mult(4).add(5).mult(6).call

console.log(main(2))
// (((2 + 3) * 4) + 5) * 6
// ((5 * 4) + 5) * 6
// (20 + 5) * 6
// 25 * 6
// 150
```

---

**Function composition**

But seriously, don't do that. Pushing everything through the `.` operator is unnatural given your starting point and you should be looking for more effective means to combine functions.

We can effectively do the same thing using a slightly different notation – the biggest difference here is complexity is almost *zero*

```js
const compose = (f,...fs) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : compose (...fs) (f(x))
  
const add = x => y => x + y

const mult = x => y => x * y

const main = compose (add(3), mult(4), add(5), mult(6))

console.log(main(2)) // => 150
```

---

**Functors**

Maybe you don't like traditional function composition, and that's fine, because we have yet *another* way to tackle this problem using *Functors* – simply put, a Functor is a container with a `map` function.

Below we have a `Box` function which puts values in our container. The `map` function accepts a function and creates a new Box with the return value of the user-specified function. Lastly, we have a `fold` function which allows us to take our value *out* of the box

Again, it changes up the way we write the code a little bit, but the reduction is complexity is tremendous (compared to the Proxy example)

```js
const Box = x => ({
  map: f => Box(f(x)),
  fold: f => f(x)
})

const add = x => y => x + y

const mult = x => y => x * y

const main = Box(2).map(add(3)).map(mult(4)).map(add(5)).map(mult(6)).fold

main(console.log) // 150
```

Comment: That's a great answer, upvoted. However, it's funny that you wrote *"Pushing everything through the . operator is unnatural in the case of javascript"*. I said funny because I'm a D3 coder, and in D3.js we do almost *everything* chaining functions. So, to me, it's very natural! Have a look ath this basic code, for instance: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for the feedback. dot-chaining actually isn't too uncommon in OOP, or even FP for that matter, but given Radex's original functions, there is no natural way to dot-chain them together. We'd need some context to wrap them in (or change the `Function.prototype`, *gasp!*) but it would dramatically change his/her starting code. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://scott.sauyet.com/Javascript/Talk/Compose/2013-05-22/

```
function add(x){
  return function(y){
    return y + x;
  };
}

function multiply(x){
  return function(y){
    return y * x;
  };
}

Function.prototype.compose = function(g) {
     var fn = this;
     return function() {
         return fn.call(this, g.apply(this, arguments));
     };
};

var f = multiply(3).compose(add(10));

console.log(f(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you are trying to figure out function chaining  in JavaScript

Function Chaining or Method chaining is a common pattern in JS world.

one of the methods in which you can achieve chaining is by creating a class and returning this operator or current object reference back

You can find interesting tutorial regarding this in following URL

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2798-using-method-chaining-with-the-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript.htm